# Flutter : Unhandled Exception: Bad state: This batch has already been committed and can no longer be changed

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I keep getting this error when trying to update multiple documents at once.

Here's my debug console:

```
 is iterator wooooooorking !!!!!0
I/flutter ( 3091): is iterator wooooooorking !!!!!1
I/flutter ( 3091): is iterator wooooooorking !!!!!2
E/EGL_adreno( 3091): tid 3281: eglSurfaceAttrib(1582): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
W/OpenGLRenderer( 3091): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x81bff820, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
I/flutter ( 3091): found data on cloudstore Instance of '_MapStream<QuerySnapshotPlatform, QuerySnapshot>'
I/flutter ( 3091): yessssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
I/flutter ( 3091): yessssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
I/flutter ( 3091): =============================================={name: bobo2012, quantity: 7, price: 5000, category: Antivirus Software, id: 2467046743, productid: 496184004787577}
I/flutter ( 3091): ==============================================7
I/flutter ( 3091): newwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwerrrrrrrrrrrrr6
E/flutter ( 3091): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: This batch has already been committed and can no longer be change
```

Here is my code:

```
  var batch = FirebaseFirestore.instance.batch();

  for (var i = 0; i < cart_numbers.length; i++) {
    print('is iterator wooooooorking !!!!!' + i.toString());

    int check_quantity;
    int new_quantity;
    int check_check;

    items() async {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("items")
          .doc(cart_numbers[i].toString())
          .get()
          .then((value) {
        print('==============================================' +
            value.data().toString());
        print('==============================================' +
            value.data()['quantity'].toString());

        update() async {
          int newer = value.data()['quantity'];
          newer--;
          print('newwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwerrrrrrrrrrrrr' + newer.toString());

          batch.update(
              //Give the ref of document.
              FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('items')
                  .doc(cart_numbers[i].toString()),
              //And the data to add in it.
              {'quantity': newer});
        }

        update();
      });
    }

    items();
  }

  batch.commit();
```